# Question about p.165 in Local Fields by Cassels

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory, class-field-theory, local-field

I am trying to understand the assertions made at the end of the paragraph below. I am not sure if I am missing some certain facts from previous chapters, but I do not see the claims made in bold typeface. Could you please guide me?

> Let $K/k$ be a finite algebraic extension and let $|\hspace{0.2cm}|$ be a valuation on $k.$ ... We do not suppose that $k$ is complete and ask ourselves what extensions, if any, there are of $|\hspace{0.2cm}|$ to $K$ ... Suppose that the valuation $|\hspace{0.2cm}|_{1}$ on $K$ extends $|\hspace{0.2cm}|$ and let $K_1$ be the completion of $K$ with respect to it. **Then $K_1$ contains the completion $\bar{k}$ of $k$ with respect to $|\hspace{0.2cm}|.$ A basis $\{B_i\}$ of $K/k$ clearly generates $K_1$ as a $\bar{k}$-vector space.**

Comment: $K_1$ is complete and contains $k$, so we can then identify the closure of $k$ in $K_1$ with the completion of $k$. For the second assertion note that any $x\in K_1$ can be approximated by elements in $K$ which we can write as a $k$-linear combination of the $B_i$. From this one can conclude that $x$ is in the $\overline{k}$-span of the $B_i$ (Maybe one has to use the fact that finite dimensional vector spaces over complete fields are again complete/all norms are equivalent for this)

Comment: @leoli1 I think for the first statement in bold typeface one also needs that given a map from a field into a complete field there is a map from the completion of the field into that complete field. Because we also want that $K_1$ contains completion w.r.t. the particular valuation.